# xpath 2.0: filter sequence using another sequence

Tags: xpath-2.0

I'm trying to filter a sequence by using another sequence in a predicate:

Here my xpath:

```
doc('files.xml')/files/file[path = //reference]
```

here the xml files:

**files.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files>
    <file>
        <path>d0002/000000338179.pdf</path>
        <file>
            <path>d0002/000000338179.JPG</path>
        </file>
    </file>
    <file>
        <path>d0002/000000341922.pdf</path>
    </file>
    <file>
        <path>d0002/000000342768.pdf</path>
    </file>
</files>
```

**references**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<references>
    <reference>d0002/000000338179.pdf</reference>
    <reference>d0002/000000341922.pdf</reference>
</references>
```

I can't get it to work, any hint is greatly appreciated.
Vlax

**EDIT**

based on the answer from @Jirka I came to a "pure" XPath expression:

```
for $file in doc('files.xml')/files/file,
$ref in //reference
return $file[path = $ref]/path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably context is changing there. So I tried use a variable and it seems to be working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="refs" select="//reference" />
    <xsl:variable name="files" select="doc('files.xml')/files/file[path = $refs]" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <files>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$files" />     
        </files>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This xslt gives a result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <file>
        <path>d0002/000000338179.pdf</path>
        <file>
            <path>d0002/000000338179.JPG</path>
        </file>
    </file>
    <file>
        <path>d0002/000000341922.pdf</path>
    </file>
</files>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Although it's not a pure XPath 2.0 answer, it's correct.